# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.bridge.RhinoInterpreterFactory incompatible with org.apache.batik.script.InterpreterFactory

Tags: java, imagemagick-convert, websphere-portal, batik

I have problem when work with Apache Batik 
I using this code to Conver SVG to JPG file. 
This my code :

```
     public static void converSVGToJPG(String path,String fileName){
        try {
             String svg_URI_input = new File(path+fileName).toURL().toString();
                TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input);        
                OutputStream jpg_ostream = new FileOutputStream(path+fileName.replace(".svg", ".jpg"));
                TranscoderOutput output_jpg_image = new TranscoderOutput(jpg_ostream);              
                JPEGTranscoder my_converter = new JPEGTranscoder();
                my_converter.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,new Float(.9));
                my_converter.transcode(input_svg_image, output_jpg_image);
                jpg_ostream.flush();
                jpg_ostream.close();      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
 }
```

But when deploy app to Websphere portal 9.0, I get a exception  :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.bridge.RhinoInterpreterFactory incompatible with org.apache.batik.script.InterpreterFactory
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext

Note that I have already exist batik-bridge-1.7.jar and batik-all-1_6.jar in my project

*How to fix it ? 
Thanks advance ! *

Comment: are you deploying as an ear, or as a war?  if you are doing it as an ear, have you sent the classload to parent last and restarted